# Extract Drive data without using WMI

Tags: c#, .net-5, hard-drive

How can I extract Drive data without using WMI at all.

I want information about the ReadTimes, IdleTimes, WriteTimes, AvgDiscSec per Read etc. per Drive but I cannot work with WMI. My project is build in .net 5.0 and already uses the DriveInfo class to get FreeSpace and TotalSpace from each drive. Additional Hardware-data was extracted with the "Win32_PerfRawData_PerfDisk_PhysicalDisk" WMI query.

I used the System.Management Package aswell as the Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure Package to extract those informations. But both fail when using it in a Jenkins setup (and apparently both because no .Net Framework was installed).

Installing a .Net Framework is not an option for me, is there another way (maybe with additional Libraries) to extract Drive data?

Comment: Are you saying that .net isn't installed on your build agent? That doesn't make any sense, because a build agent which doesn't have .net installed won't be able to build any .net application, regardless of what nuget packages they use. Can you clarify this point please, as I'm sure I'm misunderstanding?

Comment: .Net 5.0 is installed, but not .Net Framework. It seemed like System.Management and Microsoft.Management need the a Framework >4.0 to be installed

Comment: Does this answer help? It uses CIM, which gives access to the same information as WMI but is cross-platform, so shouldn't be dependent on full .net framework. https://stackoverflow.com/a/62395241/16563198

Comment: I did use Cim (which is included in the Microsoft.Infrastructure package). But It executed the Query with `FAILED`. I googled a bit and found a requirement of Framework 4.0 or higher. But It could also be that Cim needs to be executed as an Admin and I don't know how to Execute the bat script inside the jenkins job as an admin.
Note: The ``dotnet test` in jenkins is implemented as `bat "dotnet test"` and I found a couple tutorials that explain I should transfer the bat into a bat file and set the file settings to "Execute with Admin priveleges"

Comment: Sounds like running the step as admin is more likely to be the answer.